# How to handle "MongoServerError" which is causing server crash

Tags: node.js, mongodb, gridfs, multer-gridfs-storage

How to handle
MongoServerError: you are over your space quota, using 514 MB of 512 MB
in nodejs server while uploading a file using multer-gridfs-storage library

Here is my code:

```
const storage = new GridFsStorage({
    url: process.env.MONGO_CONN_URL,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise( async (resolve, reject) => {

        const filename = file.originalname;
        const shortname = await hashName();

        console.log(req.body);

        const expTime = new Date(req.body.expiryTime);
        const noOfDown = parseInt(req.body.noOfDownload);
        const isPublic = req.body.isPublic==='true';
        const passwordValue = req.body.password;

        var uploadedBy = 'anonymous';
        if(req.cookies!==undefined && req.cookies.pass!==undefined){
          try{
            const token = req.cookies.pass;
            const payload=jwt.verify(token,process.env.JWT_PRIVATE_KEY);
            uploadedBy = payload.userId;
          }catch(err){
            console.log('catch block executed');
            
          }
        }

        const fileInfo = {
          filename: filename,
          metadata:{
            shortname: shortname,
            expiryTime: expTime,
            noOfDownload: noOfDown,
            isPublic: isPublic,
            password: passwordValue,
            uploadedBy: uploadedBy
          },
          bucketName: "newBucket"
        };
        resolve(fileInfo);
      });
    }
  });  

  const upload = multer({
    storage
  });

app.post('/upload',upload.single("fileUpload"),async (req,res)=>{

    const file = req.file;
    
    console.log("File has been uploaded. File   id: "+file.metadata.shortname);
    res.send(file.metadata.shortname)

});
```

Github link: https://github.com/Dy-123/File_Sharing/blob/master/backend/index.js

I tried storage.on streamError and dbError but it is not working

Comment: In what way are you looking to 'handle' it? If you're referring to preventing the error in the first place, then searching that error text suggests that you either need to remove some data or upgrade your cluster size

Comment: here is the error msg https://p.ip.fi/z0rT which is causing server crash

Comment: is there no way to stop the server crash if there is not enough space while uploading and display mssg that server is out of storage to client?